# Multiple citation in sentence fine but citation in one bracket is problem

Tags: citing

I couldn't cite multiple author in one sentence now I can do it after editing `useage{natbib}` and citing with `\citep{key1, key2}`. I see the result (Key1 name; key2 name) which I wanted. Now I see the single cite in sentence changed and it is showing as Author (Year), but I want this as (Author, year). I cited as like as `\cite{key}`

I am using latex. `bibdesk`, in mac.

Anyone please help me My submission date is going to over. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please provide a MWE so that others can more easily address the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When the `natbib` package is loaded, `\cite` acts as a synonym for `\citet` ("textual citation"). If you want the "parenthentical citation" look, change `\cite` to `\citep`.